# do While loop crashes at second input

Tags: java, loops, do-while

I'm attempting to make a program that takes and returns distinct values in an Array. Funnily enough, the program itself works, but when I try to add a do while sentinel loop, the program crashes at the second attempt to input values. The IDE is not returning an error so I'm trying to see if my logic may be wrong somewhere?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DistinctValuesCourtney {

    static int n = 0;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        
        int[] distinct;
        int i;
        int[] array;
        array = new int[10];
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int largestValue;
        char doAgain;
    
                do {
                System.out.print("Please enter 10 integers for the array:");  //
                
                    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
                    {
                    array[i] = input.nextInt(); 
                    }
                    
                
                
                distinct = getDistinct(array);
                
                    
                System.out.print("You entered these values ");
                        for (int index = 0; index < n; index++) //use index instead of i
                        {
                             System.out.print( distinct[index] + " ");
                        }
                
                
                System.out.println("Would you like to retry? Y/N: ");   
                    doAgain = input.next().charAt(0);
                }
        
    
        
            while ((doAgain == 'Y') || (doAgain == 'y'));
                System.out.println("Have a nice day!");
        
            }
        
    public static int[] getDistinct(int[] inputArray)
    {       
        int[] finalArray = new int[10];
                
        for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++)
        {
           
            int j;                                                      //see if this is printed
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
            if (inputArray[i]== inputArray[j])
                break;
     
           
            if (i == j)
            {
            finalArray[n++] = inputArray[i];    
            //System.out.print( inputArray[i] + " ");
            
            }
        }
        return finalArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot seem to reproduce the issue with the code you have provided.

Comment: Hi Mushroomator, it's interesting. If I input the first 10 digits to an array, it works. When it asked you if you would like to retry, were you able to press Y? Did it work when you input on your second attempt?

Comment: Ok, I thought when you type the second number, but there is an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` after one presses `y` and then enters 10 numbers again. T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in your `getDistinct()` method as `n` is static and will be greater 9 the second time you enter numbers. For that reason one should generally avoid to use *global* parameters if you don't need them. Global state can cause all sort of issues.

You can just add this line (`int n = 0;`) before your `for` loop in the `getDistinct()` method and your code will work.

```java
public static int[] getDistinct(int[] inputArray)
{
    int[] finalArray = new int[10];
    int n = 0; // use a local variable here which will have value 0 everytime you execute the method!
    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++)
    {
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
            if (inputArray[i]== inputArray[j])
                break;
        if (i == j)
        {
            finalArray[n++] = inputArray[i];
            //System.out.print( inputArray[i] + " ");
        }
    }
    return finalArray;
}
```

> Just FYI: there are quicker/ better ways to eliminate duplicates e.g. using sorting with an appropriate algorithm or hashing.

Comment: I have a quick question, so I added the int n in the method however I've run into a new issue. In my loop in the main method, the loop relies on the n at for (int index = 0; index < n; index++). 

I noticed that when I added the n in the method, it will run the do/while loop however does not print the numbers. Could I just pass the value of n to another variable in this first main method loop?

Comment: You should always use the `.length` attribute if possible. This will keep you save from IndexOutOfBounds exceptions. So when you print the values don't use `index < n` but use `index < distinct.length` instead.